# Setting a background image in a div, position options

Tags: css, background-image

I know how to set a background in a div like:

```
background: url(/images/image.gif) no-repeat top right;
```

Sometimes I need more fine grained control, other than say top, center or bottom.

I have seen people using 'em' in the position section, what is that doing?

Answer (score 4):

[See the MDN reference for `background-position`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) Instead of general terms, you can also use percentages or other CSS units of measurement to set an x- or y-offset. `em` is a unit that refers to the font size for the current element, but you can also use `px` for pixel offset.

Comment: @Kzqai: good catch! Updated to point to MDN since it's more thorough anyway. For future reference, this is a pretty great example of why we allow community editing: when you see a broken link, rather than expecting the author to have kept their 3-year-old answer updated (unfortunately, the web is more fragile than we'd like), feel free to update the link yourself. After all, voting is the secondary tool in our quality control toolbox; it acts in service of making this resource the best it can be, and editing is the more productive tool here.

Comment: I might have done so, but I wasn't going to fix a broken w3schools link.  http://w3fools.com

Comment: @Kzqai: I know, I know ;) A few more years under my belt now. I wouldn't have been offended if you'd changed the source to MDN, but I hear ya.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the em is a RELATIVE size - so a 1em is a relative to my container and NOT actual size.  A 1, is a 1em based on my browsers default.

So a parent (say .parent) class with a 1em and a child with a 0.75em would be .75 of the parent.  A grandchild of that parent with 0.5em would be 0.5em of the 0.75, or approx 0.375 of the original 1em and not 0.5 of that original.

I don't use .px - it is easier to start, but when you need to change everything, you need to change it everywhere - so if you change the 1em to a 1.25em, it also changes the child and grandchild nested within those.

for a concrete example, if I put a margin-top: 0.5em; in a CSS, I am saying to put half the height of my current font as the top margin.

.px - pixels which change depending on the monitor setting and has origins in screen resolution.
.pt - is point, which means that on a printed page, 72 point is approx 1 inch - it has origins in printed material.
% has origins in well, percentage, and I find it more difficult to manage long term.
em has origins in markup.

Most browsers have 12pt (point) font as the base (if I remember correctly), which is 1em, which is - an unknown number of pixels really.  SO, off the cuff if I remember .625em is approx 10pt, so if I set the body to .625em, then my .5em below that is 5 point in size, 2em below the body would be 20 point and so forth.

EDIT: my math bites at the end of the day :)  so 10/12 is .8333 - so we need .8333 not .625, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Gradients can be controlled by

```
background:#fff url(images/vertical_sliced_image.gif) repeat-y;
```

or

```
background:#fff url(images/horizontal_sliced_image.gif) repeat-x;
```

You can slice 1px height or 1px width (Gradient image) and repeat it in the background horizontally or vertically...

hope this helps